# Entity Framework assign multiple foreign key - code first approach

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

I don't know how to add two foreign key in the following scenario:

I have two tables, one exists in the database yet (table `Market`), and I have to create a new table (`MarketBranch`).

Table `Market`:

```
public class Market
{
    public Int16 MarketId { get; set; }
    public string MarketName { get; set; }        
}
```

Table `MarketBranch`:

```
public partial class MarketBranch : BaseModelSingleUserNullable
{
    public Int16 HoldingMarketId { get; set; }
    public Int16 BranchMarketId { get; set; }
}
```

Values in table  must necessarily be the market ids present in the Market table, so I am not sure how to assign foreign keys before doing `add-migration`

What I mean is that for example I have 3 Markets (Italy with id 1, Germany with id 2 and France with id 3)

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve it, I just have to  write, in MarketBranch:

```
public partial class MarketBranch : BaseModelSingleUserNullable
{       

public Int16 HoldingMarketId {get;set;}
public Int16 BranchMarketId {get;set;}


    public virtual Market  HoldingMarket { get; set; }

    public virtual Market BranchMarket{ get; set; }      
}
```

Then, in DbContext:

```
public virtual DbSet<MarketBranch> MarketBranches { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<MarketBranch>(entity => entity.HasNoKey());
modelBuilder.Entity<MarketBranch>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.Deleted);
```

And last:

- Add-Migration MarketBranchTable
- Update-Database